# Reproducible TCP retransmission packet when using Netty

Tags: tcp, netty

I have test case where I have one channel between hosts. Client schedules 10 threads. Each thread performs 1 request over this channel. These threads get executed at the same time.
I track communication using Wireshark.
From Wireshark log I see TCP retransmission packet every time I perform execution of my test. Moreover, size of this packet is always the same.

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxLwpCjOzREAMVhmTmxic3RqQWc/edit?usp=sharing

Another test case

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxLwpCjOzREAX3BCX0d3bzEyS2s/edit?usp=sharing

Does anybody faced this kind of behaviour? What could be the reason for that?

Comment: TCP retransmits. We knew that. You may have found a reproducible case, although as your screen shots are illegible it is impossible to say. I don't see the point of the question or its relevance to SO.

Comment: Maybe it is something to do on Netty level!?